# Does the limit of this integral exist?

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $B(0,R)$ designate the open ball of radius $R>0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ($n>1$) centered at the origin. Let also $0<r<R$. We know that by smooth version of Urysohn's lemma there is a test function $\phi$ with compact support in $B(0,R)$ such that $0\leq\phi\leq1$ and $\phi=1$ on $B(0,r)$. Now, can we say that 
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow R}\int_{B(0,R)\setminus B(0,r)}\Delta\phi(x)dx=0?$$ ($\Delta$ is the laplacian)

Comment: You are integrating a continuous function over a bounded set that converges to the empty set. So the answer is surely yes?

Comment: But $\phi$ depends also on $r$. What if for example as $r$ approaches $R$, $\phi$ goes to infinity?

Comment: Oh, so you have $\phi$ depending on $r$, but are not indicating this in your notation....

Comment: I say that because $\phi$ equals 1 on $B(0,r)$ (but this is any such function), so I assume that it may depend on $r$. No?

Comment: Isn't already $\int_{B(0,R)\setminus B(0,r)}\Delta\phi(x)dx = 0$ by the divergence theorem?

Comment: @Michelle. We have $\phi(x) = 1$ for all $x$ such that $|x| \leq r$. Therefore $\nabla \phi = \vec 0$ on the same set. Since $\phi \in C^\infty$ so is $\nabla \phi$ and we must have $\nabla \phi(x) = \vec 0$ also where $|x| = r$.

Comment: I think you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

md2perpe is right:The integral 
 $$\int_{B(0,R)\setminus B(0,r)}\Delta\phi(x)dx$$ is already zero, and thus so is the limit. To see this I apply the Green's theorem:
 $$\int_{B(0,R)\setminus B(0,r)}\Delta\phi(x)dx=\int_{\partial B(0,R)}\frac{\partial\phi(x)}{\partial n}\phi(x)d\sigma+\int_{\partial B(0,r)}\frac{\partial\phi(x)}{\partial n}\phi(x)d\sigma$$
 with $\partial$ meaning boundary and $\frac{\partial}{\partial n}$ means the derivative with respect to the inward normal vector. Now the integrals of the right side are both zero; the first because the domain of integration is outside the support of the integrand, and the second because $\varphi\equiv 1$ on $B(0,r)$.